# User: Register Form won't validate

Tags: solspace-user, register

Getting an error message “You must answer the question in order to post” when trying to use Solspace's User to make a front-end registration form and can't get the form to post. Can't figure this out, totally stumped although I'm sure it's something simple. Template code is as follows:

```
{exp:user:register form:name="some_name" return="loggedin/success/newmember" allowed_groups="5|9|10|11|12" admin_register="yes"}
<fieldset>
<ul>

        <li>
    <strong>Member Name:</strong>
    <p class="instructions">This is the member's full name.  Example: Habitat Gallery & Studio</p>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="screen_name" />
    </li>

        <li>
            <strong>Username:</strong>
            <p class="instructions">A condensed version of the member name.  It is used to login and as the member's URL.  Lowercase, no spaces or special characters.  Example: habitat</p>
            <h3 class="red">Lowercase, no spaces or special characters.  Example: habitat</h3>
            <input type="text" name="username" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <strong>Member Group:</strong>
            <p class="instructions">Assign member to a group.</p>
            <select name="group_id">
                <option selected="selected">Choose a group...</option>
                {select_member_groups}
                    <option value="{group_id}"}>{group_title}</option>
                {/select_member_groups}
            </select>
        </li>

        <li>
    <strong>Description: </strong>
    <textarea name="member_description" class="textarea"></textarea>
    </li>

        <li>
    <strong>Street Address:</strong>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="member_street" id="street" onchange="geocode({address:this.value+', Foo, '+'Bar'})" 
           onfocus="this.select()" />
    </li>


        <li>
    <strong>Street Address 2:</strong>
    <p class="instructions">If you have a studio or apartment number, enter it here.</p>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="member_street2" />
    </li>

        <li>
    <strong>Zipcode:</strong>
    <input type="text" name="member_zipcode" />
    </li>


    <input type="hidden" name="member_latitude" id="latitude" />
    <input type="hidden" name="member_longitude" id="longitude" />

        <li>
    <strong>Business Hours: </strong>
    <p class="instructions">The days and hours your business is open</p>
    <textarea name="member_hours" class="textarea"></textarea>
    </li>

        <li>
    <strong>Email: </strong>
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    </li>

        <li>
    <strong>Website:</strong>
    <p class="instructions">Example: http://www.habitatgallery.com</p>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="member_website" />
    </li>

        <li>
    <strong>Facebook:</strong>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="member_facebook" />
    </li>

        <li>
    <strong>Twitter:</strong>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="member_twitter" />
    </li>

        <li>
    <strong>LinkedIn:</strong>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="member_linkedin" />
    </li>

    <li>
    <strong>Flickr:</strong>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="member_flickr" />
    </li>

        <li>
    <strong>Phone #:</strong>
    <input type="text" name="member_phone" />
    </li>



    <li>
        <strong>Categories:</strong>

        {categories}
        {category_selected}checked="checked"{/category_selected}
        {category_body}<label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="{category_id}" {selected}>{category_name}</input></label><br />{/category_body}
        {/categories}  
    </li>

    <li>
        <strong>Field of Study</strong>
        <p class="instructions">Student Members only.</p>
        <input type="text" name="member_field_of_study" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <strong>Medium</strong>
        <p class="instructions">Individual Artist Members only.</p>
        <input type="text" name="member_medium" />
    </li>

</ul>

<ul>
    <li>
        <strong>Password:</strong>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <strong>Confirm Password:</strong>
        <input type="password" name="password_confirm" />
    </li>

</ul>
</fieldset>

<input type="checkbox" name="accept_terms" value="y" checked class="hide" />  
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

{if no_results}
<p>You do not have the correct permissions to register new members.</p>
{/if}

{/exp:user:register}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your actual code does not have the {exp:user:register...} code twice, as you have it in the above code example, that error sounds like it would be related to your Register form expecting a Captcha code be entered. You'll need to put in the applicable Captcha code (or whatever code is necessary if you're using a 3rd party add-on for something more advanced than the standard EE Captcha):

```
{if captcha}
    <p>Please enter in the word you see below:
        <input type="text" name="captcha" /></p>
    <p>{captcha}</p>
{/if}
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! I actually just turned off the require CAPTCHA for Super Admins.